# What does it mean "Range"?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$c = 2 , x = Range[1,3,1] , y = c*x^2$

What is the answer?

I don't know how to solve. can anybody help me to solve?
Thanks.

**EDIT**

this's the result :
http://bit.ly/11PHGqG how this happen?

Comment: Well,
$$c = 2 , x = Range[1,3,1] , y = c*x^2$$
is not a question, so I don't know what you mean by "What is the answer?" Can you provide any context that would help other people figure out what you mean?

Comment: http://bit.ly/11PHGqG
it returns $x = {1,2,3}$ can anybody explain how this happen?

Comment: Please give the context.

Answer (score 2):

The $x$, $y$, and $z$ in `Range[x, y, z]` are called the min, max, and step respectively.  It specifies the sequence of numbers
$$x, x + z, x + 2z, \ldots$$
which starts at $x$, increases by $z$ each time, and stops after reaching $y$.

Answer (score 1):

There really is no mathematical problem here.  I believe that the term Range in this context means that x ranges from 1 to 3 in steps of 1.  That is why Wolfram returned the values of 1, 2 and 3 for x. If you are supposed to find values for y, then y = 2, 8, and 18, respectively when x = 1, 2 and 3.